# como usar SetAbsolutePosition o equivalente en una tabla creada con ITextSharp PDF C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, itextsharp

Estoy creando un pdf de un datagridview y otros datos con ITextSharp y quiero poner una tabla chica en la esquina superior derecha , justo como lo hice con la imagen a la izquierda para aprovechar el espacio como lo muestro acontinuacion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para la imagen ocupe`SetAbsolutePosition(pdfDoc.Left, pdfDoc.Top);`
pero no se cual es el equivalente para usar en tablas, a continuacion dejo el codigo que estoy ocupando

```
private void BtnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        try
        {
            int filasTotales = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
            var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 40f, 40f, 60f, 60f);
            string path = $"C:\\PDFs\\remision.pdf";
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
            pdfDoc.Open();

            var imagepath = @"C:\Users\Equipo\Documents\Interfaz\Logo\MembreteTop.png";
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                png.ScalePercent(3.3f);
                png.SetAbsolutePosition(pdfDoc.Left, pdfDoc.Top);
                pdfDoc.Add(png);

            }


            var tablacliente = new PdfPTable(new[] { .70f, 1f })
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = Left,
                WidthPercentage = 75,
                DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }

            };

            tablacliente.AddCell("CLIENTE: ");
            tablacliente.AddCell(IdClienteTxt.Text + " " + NombreClienteTxt.Text + " " + RfcTxt.Text);
            tablacliente.AddCell("DOMICILIO: ");
            tablacliente.AddCell(DomicilioTxt.Text);
           pdfDoc.Add(tablacliente);

            var spacer = new Paragraph("")
            {
                SpacingBefore = 10f,
                SpacingAfter = 10f,
            };
            pdfDoc.Add(spacer);

            iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            var headerTable = new PdfPTable(new[] { .70f, 1f})
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = Left,
                WidthPercentage = 100,
                DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }
            };

            headerTable.AddCell("REMISION: ");
            headerTable.AddCell("FECHA: ");
            headerTable.AddCell(NumeroOrdenTxt.Text);
            headerTable.AddCell(FechaTxt.Text);
            pdfDoc.Add(headerTable);
            pdfDoc.Add(spacer);

            var columnCount = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
            var columnWidths = new[] { .70f, 1.5f, .50f, .50f, .50f};

            var table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths)
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = Left,
                WidthPercentage = 100,
                DefaultCell = { MinimumHeight = 22f }
            };

            var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("ARTICULOS"))
            {
                Colspan = columnCount,
                HorizontalAlignment = 1,  //0=Izquierda, 1=Centro, 2=Derecha
                MinimumHeight = 30f
            };

            table.AddCell(cell);
            //Encabezados
            dataGridView1.Columns
                .OfType<DataGridViewColumn>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(c => table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.Name, fontTable)));
            //Filas
            int rowIndex = 0;
            dataGridView1.Rows
                .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(r =>
                {
                    rowIndex++;
                    var cells = r.Cells.OfType<DataGridViewCell>().ToList();
                    cells.ForEach(c => table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.Value.ToString(), fontTable)));
                    progressBar1.Value = (rowIndex * 100) / filasTotales;
                });


            pdfDoc.Add(table);

            pdfDoc.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Exportación Exitosa", "Exportar", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
```

En resumen quisiera que mi tabla "tablacliente" pudiera ponerla en un punto especifico de mi hojas pues como lo estoy haciendo despues de insertar la imagen automaticamente crea un salto hacia la linea de abajo, muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias poner la imagen dentro de una tabla de una sola row, de esta forma la tabla contendra la imagen en una celda y la otra table dentro de la table chica.

```
 Image png = null;
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(imagepath, FileMode.Open))
 {
    png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    png.ScalePercent(3.3f);
 }

var tableTitulo = new PdfPTable();

var cell1 = new PdfPCell();
cell1.Add(png);
tableTitulo.AddCell(cell1);

//aqui defines la tabla chica
var tablachica = new PdfPTable();
//resto codigo


var cell2 = new PdfPCell();
cell2.Add(tablachica);
tableTitulo.AddCell(cell2);

pdfDoc.Add(tableTitulo);
```

Despues por supuesto puede alinear el contenido en la tabla para que se pegue a los margenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no era lo que tenia en mente pero al final funciono muy bien ajustando algunas cosas :)